# How to remove the white space at the top of my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to remove the white space at the top of my wordpress [website](https://www.nsocompany.com/). I have tried to inspect and remove it but is not working the white space above is just annoying.

Here is also an image

The white space is the one marked in red rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that's causing this problem is this block in the screenshots below. It's adding unnecessary space to your site because of the line break (`<br>`) tag. If you can find it at the backend of your site you could just simply remove it. Or, if you can't seem to find it, you can hide it  through CSS. You can do this by going to your admin dashboard -> Appearance -> Theme Editor. Make sure `style.css` is the file shown on the screen. You can simply add this code there:

```
main #content + p, #main + p {
    display: none;
}
```

Or:

```
main #content + p, #main + p {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

1. Right click on that white space in your browser (Chrome/Firefox) then select the "Inspect option" button.
2. You will find something like `class="class-name"`.
3. Copy that class name.
4. Now go to your dashboard, then hover on the "appearance" option. There you will find the Custom CSS option. Click on it.
5. In the below example, paste the class name which you copied at the time of "inspect".
6. Use any one of `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`. See the difference.
7. For further reference, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

E.g.,

```css
.class-name
{ 
    visibility:hidden; 
    /* or */
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i tried doing but can't find the class itself, don't know if am not doing something right